# How to display an image on a qgraphicview (c++/qt)?

Tags: image, qt

i tried to display an image on qgraphicview but it does not work. Thanks in advance. Here is my code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);



QGraphicsView *view = ui->graphicsView;
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 100, 100, this);

QGraphicsPixmapItem* pixmapItem = new   QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap(":/test.png"));
scene->addItem(pixmapItem);
view->setScene(scene);
```

Comment: I solved the problem. Here is the code which works:  view->setScene(scene);
    QPixmap pix( "C:\\test.png" );
    scene->addPixmap( pix );

Answer (score 0):

Two possible issues here:

1) the path to the image file is not found. As your current code states the path to the file as *"/test.png"*, it appears that you're using OS X or Linux and the file is in the root of the file system. If the image is not in a resource, the path needs to be explicit.

I assume this is not the case and the mistake is that the file has been added to the Qt resource system, in which case, you're missing the colon, so it should be

```
QGraphicsPixmapItem pixmapItem(QPixmap(":/test.png"));
```

2) Alternatively, as you're instantiating the QGraphicsPixmap item on the stack, its likely going out of scope, so create the object on the heap:

```
// Assuming the image is in the Qt Resource system
QGraphicsPixmapItem* pixmapItem = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap(":/test.png"));
scene->addItem(pixmapItem);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding rapidly. I tested your 2 solutions but none works.

Comment: In which case, you need to expand your question, as the problem lies elsewhere. I suggest reading how to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and editing the question appropriately.